# Difference between EventEmitter.next() and EventEmitter.emit() in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

What is the difference between `EventEmitter.emit()` and `EventEmitter.next()`? Both dispatching the event to the subscribed listeners.

```js
export class MyService {
  @Output() someEvent$: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  someFunc() {
   this.someEvent$.emit({myObj: true});

   this.someEvent$.next({myObj: true});
  }
}
```

The [documenation for the EventEmitter](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/EventEmitter-class.html) is not so helpful at the moment.

Answer (score 171, accepted):

They do the same. `emit()` is the current version, `next()` is deprecated.

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/b5b6ece65a96f5b8f134ad4899b56bf84afe3ba0/modules/angular2/src/facade/async.dart#L49

Answer (score 17):

In the latest version(Ng9), the source code of `event_emitter.ts` goes as following:

```
export class EventEmitter<T extends any> extends Subject<T> {
  /**
   * Emits an event containing a given value.
   * @param value The value to emit.
   */
  emit(value?: T) { super.next(value); }
}
```

`EventEmitter` extends from parent class `Subject`. And `emit` method call `super.next()` as you may expected.