# Call function from parent angular

Tags: angular

parent.html

```
<p>parent</p>
<children></children>
```

parent.ts

```
sayhello() {
   console.log("hello")
};
```

children.ts

```
callHellotoConsole{
   this.sayhello()
}
```

How can i call sayhello() func from parent component ! 
    I already call like that

```
  <children [sayhello] = "sayhello()"></children>
```

children.ts

```
@Input() sayhello: Function;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call child component method from parent class - Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38974896/call-child-component-method-from-parent-class-angular)

Comment: @Kevin this is asking for the opposite interaction, how to call parent method from child

Comment: you need to change your question. Call function from parent, is asking how to call a function from parent (what i said was a duplicate). call parent function from child is still a duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43323272/angular-4-call-parent-method-in-a-child-component

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest not trying to invoke the parent method in the child. Consider using an event emitter to communicate to the parent from the child https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event.

Parent Component:

```js
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
    .....
    onSayHello() {
        // Execute some code
    }
}
```

Parent Component Template:

```html
<p>parent</p>
<children (sayHello)="onSayHello()"></children>
```

Child Component

```js
@Component({
   selector: 'child-component',
   templateUrl: './child-component.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./child-component.component.scss']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
    @Output() sayHello = new EventEmitter();
    .....
    sayHello() {
        this.sayHello.emit(); // you can send any variable to parent
    }
}
```

When `this.sayHello.emit();` is fired, your handler in your parent element (`onSayHello) will be called.

Here is a stackblitz [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-event-emitter)

Answer (score 1):

Do not add braces '()' with 'sayHello' while passing it as an input value to the child component.

Try like this:-

Parent.ts

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  sayHello() {
    console.log('Hello');
  }

}
```

Parent.html

```
<app-child [sayHello]="sayHello"></app-child>
```

Child.ts

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  @Input()
  sayHello: Function;

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  callHello() {
    this.sayHello();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

parent.ts

```
@ViewChild('childRef') child: ChildComponent;


child.sayhello()
```

.html

```
<children #childRef></children>
```

Comment: in what file bro ??

Comment: parent.ts as you mentioned