# call to current component method from a imported component - not parent child concept

Tags: angular, angular7

I am in `LotoReviewTabComponent` and another component is imported here -
`import { ReviewComponent } from './loto.reviewdoc.component';`

My requirement is to call a method of `LotoReviewTabComponent` inside `ReviewComponent`.

Reason `ReviewComponent`  is imported in `LotoReviewTabComponent` is - there is a modalreference call in `LotoReviewTabComponent` as below -

```
Const reviewModal = this.modalService.open(ReviewComponent, ngbModalOptions);
reviewModal.componentInstance.fileName = fileName;
```

when some event is performed in that modal - reviewModal, a method in `LotoReviewTabComponent` has to be called.

how can this be achieved?.

Comment: could you use a service to have both components call and set values?

Comment: in your child component you can inject your parent as DI(@inject(LotoReviewTabComponent)) parent: LotoReviewTabComponent)

Comment: You can use `Subject` from `RxJs` to achieve this very easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [Output event](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs#sending-data-to-a-parent-component) from angular in the ReviewComponent.

With this you can let the parent component (LotoReviewTabComponent) know that it has to do something. In this case, run a method.

Comment: the component is imported. it's not a parent

Comment: @Manojkumar The same idea still stands you just have to catch the event a little different you now have to do something like this `reviewModal.instance.nameOfOutputEvent.subscribe((event) => {yourMethod()})`

Comment: yes, I am importing the component hence it is not child. Else there is a ready example - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43323272/angular-4-call-parent-method-in-a-child-component