# Angular 11: inject service into a passed function

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

Let's say i have model class:

```js
export class Model {
  id: number;
  editAction?: () => any;
}
```

then some component creates array of those object with defined function

```js
  someArray: Model[];

  constructor(private readonly injectedService: InjectedService) {}

  private createObjects(): void {
    this.someApiService.getData().subscribe((data) => {
    this.someArray = data.map(x => 
      ({id: x.id, editAction: someEditAction})
    );
  }

  private someEditAction(): void {
    this.injectedService
      .open(/* ... */)
  }
```

then another one component, which has got `someArray` by an @Input() tries to invoke `editAction` for every element in HTML (it is all working properly):

Template:

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of someArray">
  <button (click)="item.editAction()">
</div>

Component:
@Input() someArray: Model[];
```

The problem is that after we click this button, the function "someEditAction" is actually invoked, but it does not have dependencies from it's first component and it throws error that injectedService is null. Is there any way to inject this service into that function? InjectedService is of course decorated with `providedIn: 'root'` as usual. I tried to build factoryProvider, but I think i did it wrong

Comment: Would it be possible for the child component to instead use an EventEmitter to notify the parent and have the parent call the method? If so, maybe something here would help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43323272/angular-4-call-parent-method-in-a-child-component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this:

`({id: x.id, editAction: someEditAction})`

Write this:

`({id: x.id, editAction: () => this.someEditAction()})`

This will maintain the proper `this`.

**EDIT**: Having said that, a design change in the spirit of @DeborahK's comment above should be considered.