# Angular - parent to child component, can't call methods

Tags: angular

I want to call function from parent component for get some datas but I can't. Not getting any error but it returns undefined. Where am I wrong?

**parent.component**

```js
      user:any

      dataTest(){
        console.log(this.user);
      }
```

**child.component**

```js
    @ViewChild(AppLayoutComponent) profile!: AppLayoutComponent;
    ngAfterViewInit():void{
        this.profile?.dataTest()
      }
```

Comment: `this.profile` in `ngAfterViewInit` is maybe `undefined`. Validate it via `console.log`. You get no error if you use optional chaining (`?`). Also you can only view childs with `ViewChild` as the name already says. Not parents.

Comment: yes, it returns `undefined`.

Comment: you cannot access parent from child.You should emit method via Output then on parent listen and implement.

Comment: okay, i will try, im new in angular, im just learning. @VugarAbdullayev

Comment: you can use `@Input` for pass data from parent to child.

Answer (score 0):

@ViewChild is for accessing child component from parent but you do opposite.
You should emit method on child via @Output then on parent listen and implement.

```js
    // child component
    @Output() dataTest = new EventEmitter<void>();
    
    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
      this.dateTest.emit();
    }
```

```html
    // parent html
    
    <child (dataTest)= "onDataTest()> </child>
```

```js
    // parent ts
    
    public onDataTest(): void {
    // some stuff
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no "right" way, but you can pass the method as a parameter as shown in this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68983527/3813454

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).